# Blog display code, keeping other content in post

Tags: php, blogs, preg-match-all

Alright, I have some code that will find a `<code></code>` tag set and clean up any code inside of it so it displays instead of functioning like regular code. Everything works, but my problem is how can I find the tag set/multiple tag sets inside, say, `$content`. Clean the code, and still have ALL of the other content in it? Here is my code, the problem is it checks for matches, and when it finds one it cleans it. But after it cleans it it has no way to put it back into it's original position `$content`. (`$content` is being grabbed from a form)

```
<?php
preg_match_all("'<code>(.*?)</code>'si", $html, $match);
if ($match) {
  foreach ($match[1] as $snippet) {
    $fixedCode = htmlspecialchars($snippet, ENT_QUOTES);          
  }
}
?>
```

What do I do with $fixedCode, now that it is clean?

Comment: PHP `preg` anything, is a bad use-case for this type of work. Look into a DOM parser, or hell even a Jquery/Ajax solution that will be able to select the tags, clean the code, and update the DIV with new content.

Comment: Penguin can you add that as an awesome so I can accept it? It helped me fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [regex for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1209423) is bad. I'd suggest getting familiar with a DOM parser, such as [PHP's DOM module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

> The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents through the DOM API with PHP 5.

Using the DOM module, in order to get the HTML/data from `<code>` tags in the document, you'd want to do something like this:

```
<?php
//So many variables!
$html = "<div> Testing some <code>code</code></div><div>Nother div, nother <code>Code</code> tag</div>";

$dom_doc = new DOMDocument;

$dom_doc->loadHTML($html);

$code = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName('code');

foreach ($code as $scrap) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($scrap->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES), "<br />";
}
?>
```